# Syncing events with Google Calendar

Tags: synchronization, google-calendar-api

I'm writing a service that needs an up-to-date information on a user's calendar. However, I have yet to find a way other than regular polling to receive updates from GCal. Is it possible to set up some kind of push notification or an event list diff transmission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I work for Google, and I worked on [Google Mobile Sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/), specifically calendar sync, but in this answer and everything else I write on this site, I am writing as an individual and not representing Google.)

I don't *believe* there's a public notification API, I'm afraid. As far as I'm aware, you will need to poll. However, you can of course ask for changes since a particular timestamp; it's not like you have to download the whole calendar every time.

On a secondary note: good luck! I certainly didn't appreciate just how complicated calendaring was until I started working on it...